# Having Problems Dynamically Displaying a Nested List Using Core Data

Tags: swift, sorting, core-data, nested, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Hereafter is the Problem I'm Dealing with:

- I am permanently storing information using iOS Core Data
- I would like to (dynamically) display the information stored in core data in a UITableView (as later described)
- I am considering the use of Core Data´s Fetched Results Controller (FRC) and the FRC Delegate in order to more efficiently handle the bridge between the permanently stored data and updates in the UI

> - I have a ***Person*** entity with ***name*** as an attribute.
> - I have two "to-many" relationships pointing from a *Person* to an
>   ***Employment*** Entity and two "to-one" inverse relationships pointing back, such that any person can have any number (0 to ∞) of employer(s) and any number of employee(s), simultaneously:
>
> `employee <—>> employmentTaken`
>
> `employer <—>> employmentGiven`
>
> - Every *Employment* has a ***rank*** (Int) attribute used to display a *Person*´s employer(s) - if any - to the user in an order defined by the relative income generated by each *Employment* of that *Person* (each income level being subject to  changes at any time).
> - For the program to keep track of persons shown in the UITableView, each *Employment* also comes with a ***show*** (boolean) attribute where *true* = show on the table and *false* = don't show on the table.

I would like to list *Persons* in a UITableView, such that when the user presses on a a *Person* as many rows are introduced in the UITableView under the *Person*´s name as is needed to display the Person´s Employer(s),  and so recursively (since any *Person* may both be an *Employer* and an *Employee*), the final view being a nested list.

Example as Follows:

> *Initial UI State:*
>
> **Name of Person 1**
>
> **Name of Person 2**
>
> **Name of Person 3**

...

> *UI State After the User Presses on Person 2, assuming that Person 2 simultaneously works for Person 4, 5, and 6:*
>
> **Name of Person 1**
>
> **Name of Person 2**
>
> ________**Name of Person 4** *   // 1st Source of Income by Size of Person 2*
>
> ________**Name of Person 5** *   // 2nd Source of Income by Size of Person 2*
>
> ________**Name of Person 6** *   // 3rd Source of Income by Size of Person 2*
>
> **Name of Person 3**

I am currently using NSFetchedResultsController, fetching all employments which have ***show = true*** and trying to sort them using two keys:

`let rank = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Employment.rank), ascending: true)`

`let employee = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Employment.employee), ascending: true)`

(Displaying the Name of the Person in the cell, I use the dot notation: `employment.employer?.name`)

Using those keys the order is not the desired and I'm trying to figure out if I can get the right sorting using `sortDescriptor` and the FRC.

Should I use the FRC at all or instead just create an array of arrays and write some extra code to take care of updating the UI myself?

*(I am still somewhat fresh to coding and any help would be tremendously appreciated!)*

Comment: Can you confirm what determines the order for person 1, person 2, person 3 - is that the employee.name? Are you using sectionNameKeyPath to create a section for each Employee, with cells for each Employment?

Comment: @pbasdf No, I need to sort them based on (1) the employee of the employer i.e. `employment.employee` and (2) the rank (Int) attribute i.e. `employment.rank`. I was considering using `sectionNameKeyPath` but I think I can't create new sections inside of the section, right?

Comment: Your question mentions "recursively" - how many levels deep do you want to go?  In your example, do you want to be able to tap Person 4, and have rows added to show all their employers, etc, etc?

Comment: @pbasdf As for the degree of recursion, indefinitely (in theory at least). Practically I think that 60% of use cases would not necessitate more than 10th degree, 80% not more than 20th degree, and 99.9% not more than 100th degree; so I'm not against a hard limit per se, if it's for a good reason. Say a limit to the 100th degree would make my program 10x faster in 90% of use cases, then I'd be fine with that (true not being able to use at all is a stronger case than 10x faster, but not a 900x stronger case)*

Comment: * 100% - 99.9% = 0.1% of Users Could Not Use It - 90% Would Have It 10x Faster - 90% / 0.1% = 900 - So the Ratio of Users Who Get It 10x Faster to Potential Users Who Cannot Use the Program is 900:1 - Not sure how strong of an argument "not being able to use" is compared to "10x faster", but I'd say max 100:1, including the negative fact that it's a dissuasive argument to the user to think there is a prospective limit they may hit, even if they never factually get anywhere near to be limited by it.

Comment: So I think the FRC will not be much use to you - It just doesn't natively support the recursion.  Better to maintain your own datasource.